# How to create a git hook on the server side to pull (in a path that requires root permission to modify) after it receives a push?

Tags: git, githooks

I've tried to use `post-receive` and `post-update` to:

```
cd "/home/servers/a"
git pull
exit
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I think this might be because either `post-receive` and `post-update` are not triggered after the server received a push, or it might be that for `git pull` to run successfully on the server I still need to type in the password (in this case how can I save password in the script file then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your script is executable (in your `remote_repo.git/hooks`)... and executed: for that, a simple echo "test" would be enough.

Then, when doing a `git pull`, specify the work-tree and git-dir.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/servers/a"
echo "pulling in $(pwd)"
git --work-tree=/home/servers/a --git-dir=/home/servers/a/.git pull
```

No need for `exit`.

The pull should not need a password, since the remote origin for that repo should be a relative path to the repo you just pushed to:

```
cd "/home/servers/a"
git remote -v
```

You should see `/path/to/remote_repo.git`.

---

For paths managed by root, a possible solution is, in the hooks file, to use `sudo git --work-tree=/home/servers/a --git-dir=/home/servers/a/.git pull`,  after modifying `/etc/sudoers` with:

```
dev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: git
```

(as described in "[Allow certain guests to execute certain commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215412/7490)")
If `git` is in root `$PATH`, that will work.

Comment: Does this mean within the same machine, git can do push and pull without needing a password? Sweet. I actually set up my deployment on my server as `git@127.0.0.1:/home/gitrepo/a.git`

Comment: @AeroWang check the remote used in the folder a (where you pull): if this is a path, there is no authentication needed.

Comment: It works! Okay now should I use `post-receive` or `post-update` if I want to trigger a pull after a push because neither seems to be triggered...

Comment: @AeroWang post-receive (for instance; https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838994/6309), but make sure the name of the script is post-receive without extension, and that it is executable.

Comment: Thanks! I realized the process folder /data/server requires root permission to modify files, which means `git pull` in /data/server will require password. What can I do now?

Comment: @AeroWang Execute your command with a sudo, after modifying first the sudoer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215412/7490) That way, no password required!

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused. Do you mean in my hooks file I wrote `git --work-tree=/home/servers/a --git-dir=/home/servers/a/.git pull` after modifying `/etc/sudoers` in which I add `dev ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: git` (do I need to create command alias for git btw)?

Comment: @AeroWang Yes: if the `git` command is executed as root, it will be able to write in a root-managed path). No need for an alias, just make sure git is in root `$PATH`.

Comment: Okay just to make sure...which would I write,  'sudo git' or 'git', in my hooks file?

Comment: @AeroWang `sudo git`

Comment: @AeroWang I have edited the answer to reflect this discussion in the comments.